# Twisted AMP - how to send values bigger than 64K

Tags: python, twisted, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I'm using Twisted + AMP to communicate between a server and client, both of which are Python, fully under my control. My messages are usually short, but sometimes an argument can be longer than the 64K limit. Is there any way to handle this gracefully?

I see that AMPv2 handles long messages, but I think that the Twisted implementation is for AMPv1.

I suspect chunking will be part of the answer but I'm not sure how to do that. I only have one method that is susceptible to these long messages, so I don't need the most general solution. I am open to a making different `amp.Argument` subclass if it will help.

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/fusionapp/documint/blob/8fdbaeb3aeb298afff4ba951243d03c98fe8ff99/documint/mediumbox.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code

```py
# From lp:~glyph/+junk/amphacks
"""
An argument type for sending medium-sized strings (more than 64k, but small
enough that they still fit into memory and don't require streaming).
"""

from cStringIO import StringIO
from itertools import count

from twisted.protocols.amp import AMP, Argument, Command



CHUNK_MAX = 0xffff

class BigString(Argument):
    def fromBox(self, name, strings, objects, proto):
        value = StringIO()
        value.write(strings.get(name))
        for counter in count(2):
            chunk = strings.get("%s.%d" % (name, counter))
            if chunk is None:
                break
            value.write(chunk)
        objects[name] = value.getvalue()


    def toBox(self, name, strings, objects, proto):
        value = StringIO(objects[name])
        firstChunk = value.read(CHUNK_MAX)
        strings[name] = firstChunk
        counter = 2
        while True:
            nextChunk = value.read(CHUNK_MAX)
            if not nextChunk:
                break
            strings["%s.%d" % (name, counter)] = nextChunk
            counter += 1

class Send(Command):
    arguments = [('big', BigString())]

class Example(AMP):
    @Send.responder
    def gotBig(self, big):
        print 'Got a big input', len(big)
        f = file("OUTPUT", "wb")
        f.write(big)
        f.close()
        return {}

def main(argv):
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, ClientCreator
    if argv[1] == 'client':
        filename = argv[2]
        def connected(result):
            result.callRemote(Send, big=file(filename).read())
        ClientCreator(reactor, AMP).connectTCP("localhost", 4321).addCallback(
            connected)
        reactor.run()
    elif argv[1] == 'server':
        f = Factory()
        f.protocol = Example
        reactor.listenTCP(4321, f)
        reactor.run()
    else:
        print "Specify 'client' or 'server'."
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv as arguments
    main(arguments)
```

PS: The code is taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusionapp/documint/8fdbaeb3aeb298afff4ba951243d03c98fe8ff99/documint/mediumbox.py